# Update pwsh with Scoop?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, scoop-installer

When trying to update Powershell Core with scoop via `scoop update pwsh`, I get the following error:
`ERROR Application "pwsh" is still running. Close all instances and try again.`
I tried closing PowerShell and updating via `cmd`, but it still throws that error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Scoop uses `pwsh.exe` to execute the PowerShell scripts that scoop runs on. ([scoop](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Scoop) is 96% PowerShell) Even if run in `cmd.exe`, it will still use `pwsh.exe` to execute the scripts needed to `scoop update pwsh`. This problem is solved by using Windows PowerShell, (a.k.a. PowerShell 5 / `powershell.exe`) so scoop will execute the PowerShell scripts using that instead of `pwsh`.